# Dialyzer Warnings in erlang, Records construction and improper lists

Tags: erlang, dialyzer

I am trying to fix the warnings in erlang code found from dialyzer. i came across few errors like record construction and improper lists what causes these errors. can anyone explain it.

thank you!

Comment: can you show dialyzer errors and the code (some lines)  that errors come from?

Answer (score 0):

**Proper list**:

```
[1|[2]]
```

**Improper list**:

```
[1|2]
```

...which could result from defining a function like this:

```
f([H|[]]) -> H-1;
f([H|T]) -> [H - 1 | f(T) ].
```

instead of:

```
f([H|[]]) -> [H-1];
f([H|T]) -> [H - 1 | f(T) ].
```

**Record construction error**:

http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-June/074118.html.

I do not get that record construction error in erlang 20.2.